# Change login language manually

Tags: greeter, language

My native language is Brazilian Portuguese. The system is correctly set, but the login screen remains in English, even if I apply pt-br globally in the settings screen.

Is there a way to manually set that?

Comment: Great! Thanks! I was looking for the solution as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type in terminal:

```
localectl set-locale "LANG=pt_BR.utf8"
```

Logout and check your greeter is in Brazilian.

Comment: Does this change time setting to 24h (Brazilian) as well?