# Keyboard on login screen (greeter) not changeable

Tags: greeter, keyboard

If I'm on login screen the keyboard layout is always set to US and there's no option to chose a different. It says "No other keyboard layout selectable".

[image]

This is very annoying for password entering :/
If I'm logged in everything works as expected. Correct layout is selected automatically:

[image]

Is there maybe to define a default keyboard layout that will be applied to the login screen? I deleted the US english layout but this hadn't any effect on the login screen :(

Comment: I only see "No other keyboard layouts available" - although I set German as default. On the login screen I only have the English layout, what´s a little bit confusing as I have to change "y" and "z"!

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/change-login-language-manually) advice, changing the language code to what you need (I guess German?):

```
Type in terminal:

localectl set-locale "LANG=de_DE.utf8"
```

Comment: Couldn't solve the problem - **localectl** returns:

   System Locale: LANG=de_DE.utf8
       VC Keymap: n/a
      X11 Layout: de
       X11 Model: pc105

and 
**localectl list-keymaps** returns
Couldn't find any console keymaps.

Comment: could you enter "localectl status" and paste the output?

Comment: System Locale: LANG=de_DE.utf8
       VC Keymap: n/a
      X11 Layout: de
       X11 Model: pc105

Comment: Try this: in Terminal, enter: "sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/vconsole.conf", find the line starting with "KEYMAP=..." and change it to "KEYMAP=de". Close Scratch and Terminal windows and reboot your system.

Comment: "No such file or directory" :/

Comment: aalright to be honest I did not have my system running when telling you, had it form the arch wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_console I do not have the file as well...maybe try using "localectl set-keymap --no-convert de"?

Comment: sadly didn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

I found [a solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81049) that fixed the default keyboard layout for me, but not the dropdown. At least I'm now able to login.

1. Run:
   `$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`
2. Reboot

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know, if this was the solution of the problem, but since I changed to "Secure Boot" in BIOS (My Virtualbox didn´t work after an update) everything works fine and I can use the y-key for "y" and "z" for "z"!